# Find Row in CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to reset passwords from a set username and password CSV. I have tried using the for-each method and it passes through all of the list rather than just one. Ideally I want it to ask for the username and then reset the password based on the username being entered.

The CSV is as follows

```
Daniel,Apples
Ben,Bannanas
Harry,Pears
Peter,Grapes
```

The code is very messy, but any input would be very much appreiciated. I've tried a few different ways and just can't get it to play ball!

Do I need to remove the For-Each element, basically I want it to ask me for a username and when I type it, it resets the password that is given for that username. As all are given a default password.

```
$Spreadsheet = Import-CSV "C:\Desktop\Password Reset\Passwords.csv"

$username = $User.'Username'
$password = $User.'Password'

ForEach($User in $Spreadsheet) {

$resetusername = Read-Host "Who's Password would you like to reset"

Set-ADAccountPassword $User.UserName -reset -NewPassword (Convertto-Securestring -asplaintext $($User.Password) -force)

Write-Host "Password reset to $password for $username"

}
```

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: Ther read host needs to be outside of the loop and then you need to check it with an if else statement. alternatively, use the where-object cmdlet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic approach would be to filter the list of CSV records using `Where-Object`:

```
$Spreadsheet = Import-CSV "C:\Desktop\Password Reset\Passwords.csv" -Header Username,Password

$resetUsername = Read-Host "Who's Password would you like to reset"

$targetUser = $Spreadsheet |Where-Object Username -eq $resetUsername

if($targetUser){
  Set-ADAccountPassword $targetUser.Username -Reset -NewPassword (Convertto-Securestring -AsPlainText $targetUser.Password -Force)

  Write-Host "Password reset to $($targetUser.Password) for $($targetUser.Username)"
}
else {
  Write-Host "User '$resetUsername' could not be found in spreadsheet!"
}
```

Comment: This works exactly how I wanted it to. Thank you so much! Is there any way of having it so it doesn't close down at the end of the script. And take it back to the start to add another username or does that add more complications!

Thank you so much!

Comment: @DanielDeLaWarr Put this code in a separate script or function, then call the script/function in a loop

Comment: Would I enclose the entire script in in a function named 'reset' and then use

```function reset()```